# Deserialization error : Cannot construct instance of Dto (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value

Tags: corda

Cannot construct instance of DTO (although at least one Creator exists):

```
Cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 2, column: 2].
```

I am trying to post a JSON object in corda controller. It was working fine with corda 3.3 but after upgrading to 4.1 it is giving the error

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@CordaSerializable
public class testDto {


    @JsonProperty("registrationNumber")
    private final String registrationNumber;

    @ConstructorForDeserialization
    public testDto(String registrationNumber) {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }

    public String getRegistrationNumber() {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a constructor in your DTO? If not, add one that accepts all the attributes as input parameters. If you have multiple constructors; annotate the one that accepts all attributes as input parameters with `@ConstructorForDeserialization`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: 1. Please use formatting when you post code; it's impossible to read it the way you posted it; surround the code with three back ticks in the beginning and three at the end (like this ```   some code   ```). 2. The annotation should go on the constructor not the class (I was very clear about that in my comment). 3. You can update your question and add the code there; comments are very limited in character count and formatting options.

Comment: Added the code. Have tried it both with the annotation and without the annotation

Comment: Thanx, sorry my solution didn't work.

Comment: Any particular reason why this thing is not working with just a change in version?

Answer (score 0):

There must have been an incorrect version upgrade since the serialization mechanism has changed.

Please follow the steps from the link:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/app-upgrade-notes.html

Also, please make sure you upgrade to the newest Corda web server.

Answer (score 0):

In classes with only one attribute, to deserialize an object  Json need  a nos argument constructor  from that class.

In your case you need:

```
 public  testDto() {
```

}